# APNS spoof/fake

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I want to have a standalone network (no internet access) for testing. Is there any way to spoof the APNS servers to test notifications and MDM. Is there a way to create your own APNS server.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. The APNS protocol is defined in Apple's documentation here: [The Binary Interface and Notification Formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW4). Basically, it's just an SSL server that speaks a simple binary protocol. We have implemented a mock push server and feedback server for our internal testing.

Comment: Hello, can you please share your project/code? i think it could be very usefull for other people ? Do you have a git for that project ?

Comment: I'd have to check with my employer. But the code is extremely easy to put together. I did it using the SSL support in the JDK. Once you have the input stream, you just parse it byte by byte. Apple documents the protocol in the link I provided.

Comment: Note: this link is dead. Did the documentation move somewhere else?

Comment: The link you gave shows the format of information that we can send to our spoof APN server. But it does not indicate how exactly to send this information to the IOS device. How exactly is that done? Also, the documentation says it is a "plain TCP" server, not SSL. Where does SSL come in?

Comment: @gnuf Did you found any?

Comment: @RashminJaviya It's been so many years, I don't even remember what the mock server did. But I don't think sending messages to devices was in scope. The application I was building, aggregated push notifications across multiple platforms (Google C2DM, Apple PNS, BlackBerry Push) so the mock APNS was just to ensure that the format we were sending from the aggregating server was correct. I think.